# NumberFormat not showing $ in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, format

So I have a worksheet change event, and everything works, but the numberformat does not show dollar signs on the excel sheet. The number format is accounting, and it displays two decimal places, but no $. I am not sure what to do. Please help.

```
    Option Explicit
    Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    
    Dim modifier As Range, i As Integer, j As Integer, R As Variant
    Dim counter As Integer, SheetAddress As Worksheet, SheetName As String, SheetRange As Range, cell As Range
    Dim startRng As Variant, EndRng As Variant, Brng As Range, t As Variant
    '_____________________________________|PART 1 - In $ AMOUNT|________________________________________________
    Set modifier = Range("E4:U29")
    
    'numberformat
    Range("F4:V29").NumberFormat = "_($* #,##0.00_);_($* (#,##0.00);_($* ""-""??_);_(@_)"
    
    If Not Intersect(Target, modifier) Is Nothing Then
            For i = 4 To 28
                For j = 6 To 21
                    Dim rowcount As Variant
                    SheetName = CStr(Cells(i, j).End(xlUp))
                    Set SheetAddress = Sheets(SheetName)
                    rowcount = SheetAddress.Range(SheetAddress.Cells(6, 2), SheetAddress.Cells(6, 2).End(xlDown)).Rows.Count
                    For t = 4 To rowcount
                        If SheetAddress.Cells(t, 2) >= 27 And SheetAddress.Cells(t, 2) <= 51 Then
                            If IsEmpty(startRng) Then
                                startRng = SheetAddress.Cells(t, 2).Address
                            End If
                        End If
                        If SheetAddress.Cells(t, 2) <= 51 Then
                            EndRng = SheetAddress.Cells(t, 2).Address
                        End If
                    Next t
                            
                    Set SheetRange = SheetAddress.Range(startRng, EndRng)
                    Dim offsetstart As Variant, offsetend As Variant
                    offsetstart = SheetAddress.Range(startRng).Offset(0, 9)
                    offsetend = SheetAddress.Range(EndRng).Offset(0, 9)
                    
                    'formula
                    For Each cell In SheetRange
                        If cell.Value = Cells(i, "A") Then
                            Cells(i, j) = cell.Offset(0, 9) * Cells(i, "E")
                        End If
                    Next cell
                Next j
            Next i
    End If
    
    'column totals
    For j = 6 To 21
        Cells(29, j) = WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range(Cells(29, j).Offset(-25), Cells(29, j).Offset(-1)))
    Next j
    
    'grand total
    Cells(29, "V") = WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range(Cells(29, 6), Cells(29, 21)))
    With Cells(29, "V")
        .Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0)
        .NumberFormat = "_($* #,##0.00_);_($* (#,##0.00);_($* ""-""??_);_(@_)"
    End With
    
    
    '_____________________________________|PART 2 - In UNITS (Hours)|___________________________________________
    Dim startcell As Integer, endcell As Integer, Brange As Range
    Set modifier = Range("E33:U58")
    
    If Not Intersect(Target, modifier) Is Nothing Then
            For i = 33 To 57
                For j = 6 To 21
                    rowcount = SheetAddress.Range(SheetAddress.Cells(4, 2), SheetAddress.Cells(4, 2).End(xlDown)).Rows.Count
                    For t = 4 To rowcount
                        If SheetAddress.Cells(t, 2) >= 27 And SheetAddress.Cells(t, 2) <= 51 Then
                            If IsEmpty(startRng) Then
                                startRng = SheetAddress.Cells(t, 2).Address
                            End If
                        End If
                        If SheetAddress.Cells(t, 2) <= 51 Then
                            EndRng = SheetAddress.Cells(t, 2).Address
                        End If
                    Next t
                    Set SheetRange = SheetAddress.Range(startRng, EndRng)
                    offsetstart = SheetAddress.Range(startRng).Offset(0, 9)
                    offsetend = SheetAddress.Range(EndRng).Offset(0, 9)
                    'formula
                    For Each cell In SheetRange
                        If cell.Value = Cells(i, "A") Then
                            Cells(i, j) = cell.Offset(0, 8) * Cells(i, "E")
                        End If
                    Next cell
                Next j
            Next i
    End If
    
    Range(Cells(1, 6), Cells(1, 21)).EntireColumn.AutoFit
    
    'column Totals
    For j = 6 To 21
        Cells(58, j) = WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range(Cells(58, j).Offset(-25), Cells(58, j).Offset(-1)))
    Next j
    
    'grand Total
    Cells(58, "V") = WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range(Cells(29, 6), Cells(29, 21)))
    With Cells(58, "V")
        .Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0)
        .NumberFormat = "_($* #,##0.00_);_($* (#,##0.00);_($* ""-""??_);_(@_)"
    End With
    
    
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    End Sub
```

The number format in question is on top around line 10. I just posted all the code so you can see the context of the code. As I have shown, the rest of the code works properly, however the formatting is not working. Excel shows the formatting to be Accounting, and the comment of each cell includes the $ amount, but the main cell does not show the $ sign.

Comment: `selection.NumberFormat = "_($* #,##0.00_);_($* (#,##0.00);_($* ""-""??_);_(@_)"` works for me - I see the `$`

Comment: Verify the "Currency symbol" is set correctly in Windows customize format settings. It may be overwritten with a space accidentally.  [Currency Symbol Setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sDMjZ.png)